# IIS Output caching

Tags: jsp, caching, iis

I am trying to cache the JSP or servlet response (url : /test.jsp or /test.myservlet) at IIS level by using output caching. But, not able to do so. Tried to configure from web.config as well as IIS management console.

web.config as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".myservlet" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="10:00:30" varyByQueryString="id,name" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to cache the response of the URL on extension basis when file of that extension actually does not exists on web server?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what configurations you have tried and tell us why they didn't work?

Comment: Here is the code generated from web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".myservlet" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="10:00:30" varyByQueryString="id,name" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>